# Magento newsletter ajax request returns null

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento, subscription, newsletter

I am trying to send a newsletter subscription request to Magento, but It returns null and nothing happens.

I've searched around and found very different URLs to post the request. And also grabbed the code from the file from base template.

In fact, maybe I am not sending the correct parameters or whatever.

**This is the code in use:**

```
<form method="post" id="newsletter-form">
<input type="hidden" class="url" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new') ?>">
    <input id="newsletter" type="text" name="email" placeholder="RECEBA NOVIDADES" value="" class="input-text myFormInput" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" style="width: 188px !important">
    <button type="submit" id="ajax-newsletter-submit" title="CADASTRAR" 
    class="button myFormButton" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left: -107px !important;width: 103px">CADASTRAR</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**:

```
   var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-form');

   $j(function() {
       $j("#ajax-newsletter-submit").click(function() {        
        var email =$j("#newsletter").val();
        var url=$j(".url").val();
        var dataString = 'email='+ email;
            if(email=='') {
               $j("#newsletter").focus();
            } else {
                var a = email;
                var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{1,4}$/;
                if(filter.test(a)){
                    $j.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(){                
                            alert('Assinatura realizada com sucesso!');
                            $j("#newsletter").val('');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $j("#newsletter").focus();
                }
            }  
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: what's the value of `var url=$j(".url").val();`?

Comment: Share controllerAction code, may be error will be in php code.

Comment: I don't have a controller. What code should I put in a controller?

Comment: @OSdave The value for the URL is in the hidden input <?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new') ?>

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
 var val_form = new VarienForm('your form id');
jQuery("#your form id").submit(function(e)
{
    if (val_form.validator && val_form.validator.validate())   
    {        
        var postData = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = jQuery(this).attr("action");
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {   
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Failure');
            }
        });
        this.reset(); //form field reset
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
    }
});
```